# how to registering css files locating in module in yii1

Tags: yii

I am a new yii developer. I have index file in `protected/modules/profile/views/company/index.php.` I wanted to register css files locating in `protected/modules/profile/css` folder. So, i used following formula:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->basePath?>'/modules/profile/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css' media="print">
```

But, nothing is happening.
Please, help me where i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/modules/profile/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```